Reducing request header size dynamically (deleting cookies)
I'm using an Oauth/PCKE mechanism to authenticate users on my web app. Until recently, everything worked fine.
I'm using Supabase: with their auth a JWT token gets stored as a cookie. It looks like, after a migration, multiple of such cookies get passed along with a single request to my front-end, exceeding a critical limit of 16kb, which means these requests get throttled in some scenarios.
In particular, GET requests to my NEXTJS middleware bounce because of this.
I want to catch such scenarios and redirect my users to a page, where I can execute code that prunes existing cookies or handles with the problem in some other way.
However I cannot find any documentation on the web on how to handle these requests, except reducing header size.
How can I reduce the header size when I cannot even reach the middleware?
